# Getting an Array of all items from an Enum in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, enumeration

I'm trying to get all items of a TypeScript Enumeration. For this I use the following, generic function:

```
static getAllValues<T>(enumeration: T): Array<T>{
    let enumKeys: Array<T> = Object.keys(enumeration).map(k => enumeration[k]);

    let items: Array<T> = new Array<T>();
    for(let elem of enumKeys){
        if (typeof(elem) === "number"){
            items.push(elem)
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

By calling this function with an Enum of the Type `ExampleEnum` like

```
export enum ExampleEnum {
 FOO,
 BAR,
 FOOBAR
}
```

I expected a return value from the type `Array<ExampleEnum>` but the response is from the type `Array<typeof ExampleEnum>`.

Does anyone know how to fix it, to get a return from the type `Array<ExampleEnum>`?

(I'm using TypeScript 3.2.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in the container object for the `enum` so `T` will be the container object. The container object is not the same type as the enume, it is an object that contains values of the enum, so its values will be of the enum type which we can get at using `T[keyof T]`

```
function getAllValues<T>(enumeration: T): Array<T[keyof T]> {
    let enumKeys = Object.keys(enumeration).map(k => enumeration[k]);

    let items = new Array<T[keyof T]>();
    for (let elem of enumKeys) {
        if (typeof (elem) === "number") {
            items.push(elem as any)
        }
    }

    return items;
}

export enum ExampleEnum {
    FOO,
    BAR,
    FOOBAR
}

getAllValues(ExampleEnum);
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you think of this version of the function, shorter and still handling `string enum` too?

```
function enumValues<T extends object>(enumeration: T): Array<T[keyof T]> {
    return Object
        .keys(enumeration)
        .filter(k => isNaN(Number(k)))
        .map(k => enumeration[k]);
}

enum ExampleEnum {
    FOO = 10,
    BAR = 20,
    BAZ = 30
}

console.log(enumValues(ExampleEnum)); // [10, 20, 30]

enum ExampleStringEnum {
    FOO = 'F',
    BAR = 'B',
    BAZ = 'Z'
}

console.log(enumValues(ExampleStringEnum)); // ['F', 'B', 'Z']
```

Comment: Wow, I did not think about that. Although I do not need the string values but through the early filtering, the computing effort will probably be significantly reduced. Thanks!